# Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type ArrayList<Foo>

Tags: java, android, generics

The following code:

```
((tempVar instanceof ArrayList<Foo>) ? tempVar : null);
```

causes:

> Cannot perform `instanceof` check against parameterized type `ArrayList<Foo>`. Use the form `ArrayList<?>` instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime

Can someone explain me what is meant by "further generic type information will be erased at runtime" and how to fix this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It means that if you have anything that is parameterized, e.g. `List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();`, the Generics information will be erased at runtime. Instead, this is what the JVM will see `List fooList = new ArrayList();`.

This is called [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The JVM has no parameterized type information of the `List` (in the example) during runtime.

A fix? Since the JVM has no information of the Parameterized type on runtime, there's no way you can do an `instanceof` of `ArrayList<Foo>`. You can "store" the parameterized type explicitly and do a comparison there.

Comment: `You can "store" the parameterized type explicitly and do a comparison there.`

Could we see an example of this?

Comment: @jocull 4 years since your question, almost twelve since his original post and Buhake still does not respond despite being very active on SO. I really dislike hit and runs like this.

Comment: @jocull and @Andrew S, I apologize for not responding. What I meant to say is that you have to keep reference what the parameterised type that is stored in the `List` so that you can do an `instanceof` of the object with what is stored in the list.

Answer (score 32):

You could always do this instead

```
try
{
    if(obj instanceof ArrayList<?>)
    {
        if(((ArrayList<?>)obj).get(0) instanceof MyObject)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
catch(NullPointerException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what about if it's empty

Comment: @RafaelRuiz I think a simple try/catch cast to the right type ArrayList<MyObject> would do the trick?

Comment: You can do this if you know that Foo class is MyObject class.

Answer (score 11):

Due to type erasure, the parameterized type of the `ArrayList` won't be known at runtime. The best you can do with `instanceof` is to check whether `tempVar` is an `ArrayList` (of anything). To do this in a generics-friendly way, use:

```
((tempVar instanceof ArrayList<?>) ? tempVar : null);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is sufficient:

```
if(obj instanceof ArrayList<?>)
{
   if(((ArrayList<?>)obj).get(0) instanceof MyObject)
   {
       // do stuff
   }
}
```

In fact, `instanceof` checks whether the left operand is `null` or not and returns `false` if it is actually `null`.
So: no need to catch `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Would this not be better suited towards a comment on the original post?

Comment: No need to catch NullPointer, but you need to catch IndexOutOfBounds

Answer (score 2):

You can't fix that. The type information for Generics is not available at runtime and you won't have access to it. You can only check the content of the array.

Answer (score 2):

instanceof operator works at runtime. But java does not carry the parametrized type info at runtime. They are erased at compile time. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this

Create a class

```
public class ListFoo {
  private List<Foo> theList;

  public ListFoo(List<Foo> theList {
    this.theList = theLista;
  }

  public List<Foo> getList() {
    return theList;
  }
}
```

Is not the same but ...

```
myList = new ArrayList<Foo>;
.....
Object tempVar = new ListFoo(myList);
....
((tempVar instanceof ListFoo) ? tempVar.getList() : null);
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform an exact check type instead of this:

```
protected <Foo> ArrayList<Foo> myMethod(Object tempVar ) {
    return tempVar instanceof ArrayList<Foo>) ? (ArrayList<Foo>) tempVar : null;
}
```

You can do this:

```
protected <Foo> ArrayList<Foo> myMethod(Object tempVar, Class<Foo> clz) {
    if (tempVar instanceof ArrayList && (tempVar.size() == 0 || clz.isInstance(tempVar.get(0))))
        return (ArrayList<Foo>) tempVar;
    return null;
}
```

In this way your code is full secured.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
boolean isInstanceArrayList = tempVar.getClass() == ArrayList.class
```