# How to know if a java object is a List

Tags: java, list, instanceof

I would like to know how to ask if a java object is a List or an ArrayList.

For example:

```
if (Object instanceof List <?>)) {
    // Do something
}
```

PS: I have several lists of different types and would like to implement the method for any list no matter what type of data they contain.

Comment: Just get rid of the `<>`.

Comment: An `ArrayList` _is_ a `List`.  Are you asking if it's another implementation of `List`?

Comment: you can also use .getClass method and check what it returns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test if an instance is a `List` or an `ArrayList`<sup>1</sup>, just use `instanceof`.

Note that according to the JLS [15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2), the type operand of the `instanceof` operator must be a reifiable type, and that is defined in JLS [4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7) as:

- a parameterized type in which all type arguments are unbounded wildcards,
- a raw type
- a primitive type (not applicable in this context
- an array type whose element type is reifiable, or
- a nested type where, each enclosing type is also reifiable.

So both of these should be valid:

```
if (obj instanceof List)) {     // raw type
    // Do something
}
if (obj instanceof List <?>)) { // type parameter is an unbounded wildcard
    // Do something
}
```

but this would be a compilation error:

```
if (obj instanceof List <Integer>)) {
    // Do something
}
```

---

> I have several lists of different types and would like to implement the method for any list no matter what type of data they contain.

That's no problem.

(But it would be a problem if you wanted the method to only work for lists with certain kinds of data ... based on a simple runtime typecheck.  The type parameters for a generic type are not available at runtime for runtime tests, so you would need to test each element of the list individually ...)

---

<sup>1 - Note that any `ArrayList` is *also* a `List` ... because the `ArrayList` class implements the `List` interface.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

"List" is only an interface. The implementation is eq. "ArrayList" or "LinkedList".

But here is another topic from Stackoverflow:

[how-to-instanceof-listmytype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108122/how-to-instanceof-listmytype)