# Does the javac compiler create a different class for every type when use generics?

Tags: java, class, generics, compiler-construction, bytecode

If I have a generic class, does the compiler create a different class for every type I use with it? Let's consider this `Class<T>`. If I create  two instances of type `Class<Integer>` and `Class<String>`, does the compiler create two different classes?

If the answer is no: how it's possible that classes that extend a generic class can inherit the same method or attribute with a different type (from a single class).?

Another question: why can't I check `var instanceof Class<Integer>` using parameterized type instead of `Class` or `Class<?>`?

If I try to do this, I get the following  error:
"Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type `Test<Integer>`. Use the form `Test<?>` instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime"

Can you give me more information about generics?

Comment: The short answer is No. Type parameters are just that... Parameters.

Comment: Look up Type erasure.

Comment: No, which is why you can't actually tell which generic type was used in many cases at rutime.  It is a compile time feature.

Comment: This question is a teaching book example of a duplicate... it is so common, it has a dedicated section in the Oracle tutorial. Please refer duplicates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If I have a generic class, does the compiler create a different class for every type I use with it? Let's consider this Class. If I create two instances of type Class and Class, does the compiler create two different classes?

No, there is a single class, and in the bytecode, all appearances of the type variables are effectively replaced with their upper bound (typically `Object`, but possibly some type `U` for type variables of the form `T extends U`).  This concept is called *type erasure* because the type variables are effectively *erased* (and replaced with their upper bounds).

> If the answer is no: how it's possible that classes that extend a generic class can inherit the same method or attribute with a different type (from a single class).?

Interesting question!  Let's say you have two different classes that implement `Comparator<T>`.  One implements `Comparator<String>`, and the other implements `Comparator<Integer>`.

`Comparator<T>` defines the following method:

```
int compare(T p0, T p1)
```

So how do two different generic instances implement the same method with different argument types?  Well, the method implemented in code doesn't actually override `Comparator.compare()`.  `Comparer.compare()` accepts two `Object` arguments, but `Comparator<String>.compare()` accepts two `String` arguments.  They're not the same method.  So, then, why does it *behave* like an override?  Because the compiler generates a hidden *bridge method* for you.  Run a generic implementation through a decompiler or disassembler to see for yourself.  The following is output from my own [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon) decompiler run with `--show-synthetic`:

```
public enum StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    ORDINAL {
        @Override
        public int compare(final String s1, final String s2) {
            if (s1 == null) {
                return (s2 == null) ? 0 : -1;
            }
            if (s2 == null) {
                return 1;
            }
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }

        @Override
        public /* bridge */ int compare(final Object x0, final Object x1) {
            return this.compare((String)x0, (String)x1);
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

The first `compare()` method is the actual implementation written by the author of the `StringComparator` class.  The second method is hidden, and was generated by the compiler.  It exists to "bridge" the generic implementation with its "erased" definition, and it is this bridge method which implements the interface method `Comparator.compare()`.  Note how the bridge method uses type casts to enforce the binding of `T` to `String`.  This provides a measure of safety in a world of type erasure.  It ensures the following produces an exception:

```
class IntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer> { ... }

// 'c' is a raw Comparator, or effectively a Comparator<Object>
// (note the lack of type arguments).
Comparator c = new IntegerComparator();
int result = c.compare(1, "hello");
```

The code above compiles fine, because the raw form of `Comparator.compare()` accepts two `Object` arguments.  But at runtime, the call will trigger a `ClassCastException` because the bridge method in `IntegerComparator` will attempt to cast the string "hello" to an `Integer`.

> Another question: why can't I check var instanceof Class<Integer> using parameterized type instead of Class or Class<?>?

Since all instances of a concrete generic type share the same class, wherein all type variables have been erased, a generic class instance has no sense of identity beyond its raw type.  It doesn't know the type arguments with which it was instantiated, because that information has been boiled away during compilation.  If you instantiate an `ArrayList<String>`, the resulting instance only knows it is an `ArrayList`.  A check of `instance instanceof ArrayList<String>` cannot produce a meaningful result in this case.  Since such checks cannot reliably<sup>1</sup> produce meaningful results, they are disallowed.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Interestingly, an instance of the `StringComparator` class above *does* know that it implements `Comparator<String>`, as generic supertype information is retained in the metadata.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

No, the class are same for any `<XXX>`. Generics exists only before compilation and not in bytecode. This is done for backward compatibility.

For further information you may want to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 0):

No, there is only one class, as the parameterized type is only known at the runtime, compiler can't create class for each matching types.

When you extend a generic class, methods and member are inherited. I don't understand your purpose...
For example:

```
public class MyClass<T> extends AbstractMyClass<T> {

    @Override
    public void add(T element) {
        // do something with element...
    }


}

   public class MyClass<T> {
       private final List<T> store = new ArrayList<T>();

       protected void add(T element) {
          store.add(element);
       }
  }
```

[edition] Ok, I think I did not understand your question about the extend the first time... sorry.[/edition]

And you can not check instanceof because parameterized type is not known at the runtime.
You can try something like that : [how to instanceof List<MyType>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108122/how-to-instanceof-listmytype) to check if your parameterized types are the same.