# Get type of List<MyModelClass>

Tags: android, list, generics, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm inflating multiple layout views in `recycylerView` and getting `viewType` by overriding `getItemViewType()` method as

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        Log.e("getItemViewType ", myAllItemsList.get(position).getClass()+"");
        if (myAllItemsList.get(position) instanceof MyCategory) {
            return CATEGORY_VIEW;
        } else if (myAllItemsList.get(position) instanceof MyPromotion) {
            return PROMOTION_VIEW;
        } else {
            return ITEM_VIEW;
        }
    }
```

As `myAllItemsList` is of type Object

```
private List<Object> myAllItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I'm passing three types of objects to it

1. `List<MyCategory>`
2. `MyPromotion`
3. `List<MyItem>`

on calling the above method the `if condition` never execute as there is nothing like MyCategory in `myAllItemsList` But instead it contain `List<MyCategoty>`. When I try

```
myAllItemsList.get(position) instanceof List<MyCategory>
```

Android Studio says `Illegal generic type for instenceof`.

So my question is how can I get to know the `myAllItemsList` contains `List<MyCategory>` so that I would `return CATEGORY_VIEW`.
Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108122/how-to-instanceof-listmytype)

Comment: You can wrap `List<MyCategory>` inside `Categories` class (for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by Getting Object and 1st check for if its of type `List` then iterate this list's element and check If it's `instenceof MyClass` (MyCategory).

```
Object o = myAllItemsList.get(position);
        if (o instanceof List) {
            for (Object obj : (List) o) {
                if (obj instanceof MyCategory) {
                    Log.e("InsideInstenceof", "Success");
                    return CATEGORY_VIEW;
                }
            }
            return ITEM_VIEW;
        } else if (o instanceof MyPromotion) {
            return PROMOTION_VIEW;
        }
```