# Unchecked or unsafe operations at ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, objectinputstream

I'm getting a "Unchecked or unsafe operations" error at this method:

```
public static MyClass initApp(){
        MyClass obj = new MyClass(); 
        try{
            ObjectInputStream oin = 
                new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.dat"));

            obj.setSomeList ( (Map<String,MyOtherClass>) oin.readObject()); //error line

        }catch(IOException e)
            { System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }
         catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
            { System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }

        return obj; 
    }
```

Isn't Map the most abstract as possible in this case? How can I solve this?

Method setSomeList (NOTE! It is placed in another class! If that helps):

```
public void setSomeList(Map<String,MyOtherClass> l){
        for(Map.Entry<String,MyOtherClass> entrada : l.entrySet())
            someList.put(entrada.getKey(),entrada.getValue().clone());
    }
```

Comment: Right now you are just assuming that the Object read from the stream is a Map<String, MyOtherClass>. You should double check the class of the object read before casting.

Comment: @CConard96 How can I do that in ObjectInputStream "environment"?

Comment: idk whats going through your mind but why u trying to cast oin.readObject(), can u tell me

Comment: show us the method setSomeList

Comment: @holidayCoder because if I don't there is a incompatible types error

Comment: @NicolasFilotto done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only a warning, you could simply ignore it as it doesn't prevent your application to work unless it is not the right type, if you want to remove it simply add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` at the method definition level, as below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static MyClass initApp(){
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way?

Comment: no because you convert an Object into a Map, it is part of the compiler's job  to warn you that it could fail, but if you know that it is safe you simply add a warning, it is a way to say ok no problem I know what I'm doing

Answer (score 1):

You should check the objects type before casting.

```
Object theObject = obj.readObject();
if (theObject instanceof Map)
{
    Map theMap = (Map) theObject;
    objSetSomeList(theMap);
}
```

Comment: There is no way to check the types of the keys or values at that point in the code because of type erasure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335018/cannot-perform-instanceof-check-against-parameterized-type-arraylistfoo for more info. Best you can do is cast to generic Map<Object, Object>, get the first entry, check types of key and value using instanceof.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks ;)